# How can I use default configuration and default test listeners for all my Spring tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have several dozen tests that all use the same configuration and listeners for all tests. This means the follow lines are repeated:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebDriverConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {ScreenshotTaker.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
```

I've created the following:

```
public class WebDriverRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public WebDriverRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContextManager createTestContextManager(Class<?> clazz) {
        return super.createTestContextManager(ConfigShim.class);
    }

    @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebDriverConfig.class)
    @TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {ScreenshotTaker.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
    public static class ConfigShim {

    }
}
```

Which means I can run tests as follows:

```
@RunWith(WebDriverRunner.class)
public class ShoppingCartPageIT {
```

But, this changes the names of the test.

Comment: Please do **not** extend `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. JUnit runners are becoming a thing of the past and will likely be unsupported in JUnit 5 and Spring Framework 5.

Comment: Instead, the better option is to create a custom _composed annotation_ as mentioned in the answer from @jny.

Comment: Fantastic Sam. It's going in the book :)  Is there a JUnit 5 road-map anywhere I can read about?

Comment: You can find out more about JUnit Lambda (a.k.a. JUnit 5) here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit-lambda/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spring Framework 4.1 or higher, you can create your own [composed annotation](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-meta-annotations/) for testing configuration:

Define your annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebDriverConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    ScreenshotTaker.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class
})
public @interface WebDriverTestConfig {}
```

and then annotate your tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebDriverTestConfig
public class ShoppingCartPageIT { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: JUnit's `@RunWith` can not be used as a meta-annotation. As I have mentioned elsewhere on Stack Overflow, this has nothing to do with Spring. JUnit simply does not support meta-annotations at all. I am therefore editing your answer accordingly.

Comment: I also added the missing `@Retention` and `@Target` declarations.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam Brannen, for you clarification